# Secure submit form with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, security

For my project, i use a submission form by JS(Vanilla) function (form.submit()).

When the form is complete, my app send an email (i call a Symfony function with AJAX for send the email.) with a random code(generate via a JS function) to the user.

This code must be enter in an input to submit the form.

But big problem, if y use my browser's console and i type :

```
document.getElementById("sharing_form").submit();
```

The form is submitted...  ! Normal but is not safe, the code is useless !

Do you know how to secure this ? How to submit form ONLY with the generated code ?
Maybe another way ?

Thanks

Comment: This will be secure if the `action` URL uses `https:`

Comment: Thanks but i want to secure the submission with my generated code.

Comment: Put the generated code in a hidden form field.

Comment: You need to specify the threat you're trying to defend against when you ask about security.

Comment: My generated code work great at this Time. But when i use the browser console and write document.getElementById("sharing_form").submit() the form is submited even if the code is not entered...

Comment: You can't do anything at the client end to protect against this, it must be done by the validation code on the server.

Comment: F12 developer tools can let someone see anything you do client-side, and they can also modify your script code or inject any script code of their own.  They can also use cURL or similar to not use a browser at all and  ignore any of your javascript that they want.  It is never safe to rely on the client side.

Comment: Ok thanks you. I will do it with a PHP function and test the code After the form submission (and before write datas in my dB)

Comment: Note that this does not solve the issue of people being able to submit anything to your backend, in case that's what you wanted. Anybody can still just query a code, craft any request they want, and send that with the code. In other words, your client cannot "sign" (or create message authentication) for requests, your backend simply cannot trust requests and validations must be implemented server-side, but likely not for a code it created and shared with the client anyway, but for correctness, whatever that means in your case.

Comment: The main use for client-side validation is to stop the user from making a mistake.  Like if you are having them enter their email address twice, you can compare them client-side to make sure that they match before submitting the form.  The server must still do its own validation and it never trusts the incoming data

Comment: Yes thanks you. I do client-side and server-side value checks. With REGEX CSRF token, htmlspecialchars() etc. Im beginner